# How to dump txt file in C?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

    int name;
    int arrival_time;
    int size;

    int ret;

    FILE * fp = fopen_s("C:\\NIA\\data.txt", "rt");

    while (1)
    {
        ret = fscanf_s(fp, "%d %d %d", &name, &arrival_time, &size);
        if (ret == EOF)
            break;

        printf("%d %d %d \n", name, arrival_time, size);


    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

I want to dump my txt file to project but errors are coming out. I'm confused about memory initiation and file format, variables, etc. How can I fix this and print values well?

My txt file is :
[image]

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with the code. You should describe what errors you see. Hard to help when you don't give all the information. Also when you open a file, you should always check if the file has opened successfully, you aren't doing that in the code above.

Comment: Hi, I rolled it back so that callers can see what you wrote. It's not a good idea to update the posted code to track responses. People won't know why you asked the question.

Comment: After validating a successful open, why not `while (fscanf_s(fp, "%d %d %d", &name, &arrival_time, &size) == 3) printf("%d %d %d \n", name, arrival_time, size);` ?? Your variable declarations are fine, you have variables (with *automatic storage duration*) you are simply reusing.

Comment: "errors are coming out" -  what errors?

Comment: Unless you open text files using Gimp/Photoshop etc. you should not make a screenshot of them but simply insert the text via copy&paste. This is also 10 times faster than making a screenshot, saving it to file, uploading to some webpage and inserting a link into the question. Everyone wanting to reproduce your problem using your input data now has to retype manually instead of copying from your question.

Comment: BTW: Does this even compile? `FILE * fp = fopen_s(...` According to manual the function takes different parameters and has different return value: `errno_t fopen_s(FILE** pFile, const char *filename, const char *mode);`

Answer (score 1):

Your question lacks the most important information: What is going wrong.

When I compile your code, I get errors for `fopen_s`. (OK, this is mainly because I use gcc ;) )

The [manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fopen-s-wfopen-s?view=msvc-160) tells us how this function looks like:

```
errno_t fopen_s(
   FILE** pFile,
   const char *filename,
   const char *mode
);
```

This means, you must use it like this:

```c
   errno_t  err;
   FILE    *fp;

   err = fopen_s(&fp, "C:\\NIA\\data.txt", "rt");
   if (err != 0)
   {
      fprintf(stderr, "The file was not opened\n" );
      exit(1);
   }
```

Or you stick to standard functions and use them as you already tried:

```c
   FILE    *fp;

   fp = fopen("C:\\NIA\\data.txt", "rt");
   if (fp = NULL)
   {
      fprintf(stderr, "The file was not opened\n" );
      exit(1);
   }
```

You should definitely add checks for all return values. At least for I/O related functions like `fopen` and `scanf`.

Also closing your file would be adviseable. While it is only opened in read mode, it will not cause much trouble as it is closed automatically on program termination, but it is surely good style to do it.

An improved version could look like this:

(As you do not scan strings, there is no benefit using MS non-standard function `scanf_s`)

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    int name;
    int arrival_time;
    int size;

    FILE * fp = fopen("data.txt", "rt");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        perror("File data.txt cannot be opened");
        exit(1);
    }

    while (fscanf(fp, "%d %d %d", &name, &arrival_time, &size) == 3)
    {
        printf("%d %d %d\n", name, arrival_time, size);
    }

    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

This prints the content of your data.txt file on the console.

Answer (score 0):

If dumping you txt file means closing the txt file after using it, you can use the following

```
fclose(fp);
```

before the `return 0;`

Comment: Thanks for the comment. But I still get errors and can't make expected output.

Comment: Any open file is closed on program exit anyway, but it's good to be tidy.

Comment: @PareKanes *I still get errors* Why are you not able to say what those errors are? Do you want some help or not?

Comment: While I agree that closing a file is always a good idea, how would closing an input file have any effect on behaviour of the program?